# change bitrate of mp3

Tags: java, audio, xuggle

I am using xugglu in java in order to switch the bitrate of the input MP3 file, storing it in a output file. I took one example I found on the net the loads the file to a reader and adds a writer as a listener. Does anyone know how can I then modify the bitrate?

Here's the code I've been using:

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaViewer;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class TranscodingExample {

private static final String inputFilename = "/home/user/Desktop/file_changed.mp3";
private static final String outputFilename = "/home/user/Desktop/file_changed.flv";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create a media reader
    IMediaReader mediaReader =
           ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);

    // create a media writer
    IMediaWriter mediaWriter =
           ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename, mediaReader);

    // add a writer to the reader, to create the output file
    mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);

    // create a media viewer with stats enabled
    IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);

    // add a viewer to the reader, to see the decoded media
    mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);

    // read and decode packets from the source file and
    // and dispatch decoded audio and video to the writer
    while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;

}
}
```

EDIT-1:

I couldn't really get around this one, so I just used a linux command doing that inside the Java app. You can find a reference to the code [here](http://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/getting-started-with-javas-processbuilder-a-sample-utility-class-to-interact-with-linux-from-java-program/). The command I used was:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -b 112k out.mp3
```

It converts the mp3 to a new one of bitrate equal to 112k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [IAudioResampler](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/IAudioResampler.html):

> Used to resample IAudioSamples to different sample rates or number of channels.